# Imacros extract and value to impose conditions

Tags: javascript, imacros, data-extraction

I want an "If statement" in Imacros, the condition depends on the current balance. For example. 
1) Extract balance (save as variable), 
2) Perform task 1, 
3) IF previous balance > current balance,
4) Perform task 1,
5) else, 
6) Perform task 2

I learned how to extract data, but How do I save it as variable to be compared in step 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use "If" or similar, you must use JavaScript. Here you have this link from someone asking something similar in another forum. You can use it as an example:

[IMacros](http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=14010)
I hope you find it useful.